# Not understanding a line in a proof concerning Monomorphism and injectivity

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, monomorphisms

In the proof that "in the category Div of divisible (abelian) groups and group homomorphisms between them there are monomorphisms that are not injective" given in Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphism (see the Examples section) , the proof assumes at one point that $h(y) \in \mathbb Z$ , I don't understand this , please help

EDIT : one other thing ; at the end , they take the morphisms $f,g$ with range deliberately $\mathbb Q$ and not arbitrary divisible groups , why is that ?

Comment: I see that you have created (proof-clarification) tag. Is there some substantial difference from the already existing ([tag:proof-explanation]) tag?
(This tag was [discussed on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12465/proof-explanation-tag) before.) I think it is better to use already existing tags than to create new ones.

Comment: @MartinSleziak : Well it is not that I did not understand the whole proof , just only a part (minor ) of it , so I mentioned "clarification" and not "explanation" , but if you feel , you are free to delete the tag

Comment: I have [edited the tags](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1153034/revisions). (I think sooner or later somebody would do it. Especially considering that some users thing that [almost every new tag should be discussed on meta first](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17023/).) If you think that (proof-clarification) could be useful tag and it should be added, you can still open a discussion on meta about this tag.

Answer (score 0):

The map $h: G \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ in the example is a function with the property $q \circ h = 0$ where $q : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the quotient map. Now note that the property $q \circ h = 0$ is equivalent to $h(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $x \in G$, in particular we have $h(y) \in \mathbb{Z}$.