# Monomorphisms and injectivity predicates

Tags: category-theory, monomorphisms

This is a curiosity question which struck me at a less-than-optimal moment; I apologize for not having thought much about it.

**Motivation.** It is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153034/not-understanding-a-line-in-a-proof-concerning-monomorphism-and-injectivity) that monomorphisms in a concrete category need not be injective maps. As far as I understand, a concrete category that has "forgotten" its realization (i.e., forgetful functor to $\operatorname{Set}$) just does not "know" which of its maps are injective. The notion of a monomorphism is only an "upper bound" on the injective maps (i.e., each morphism which is injective as a map is a monomorphism, but not conversely). Now, if I have a (non-concrete) category and want to "tell it what its injective morphisms are" without giving it a realization, I see two ways how I could go: Either I could just specify which of its morphisms I regard as injective (by what I call an "injectivity predicate" below), or I could try to embed it into a larger category and say that the injective morphisms are the monomorphisms which are still monomorphisms in the larger category. The below question essentially is "are these two ways equivalent?".

**Question.** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. A *wide subcategory* of $\mathcal{C}$ will mean a subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ whose objects are all objects of $\mathcal{C}$. (Some people call this a "lluf subcategory" of $\mathcal{C}$.) Let $\operatorname{Mono} \mathcal{C}$ be the wide subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ whose morphisms are the monomorphisms of $\mathcal{C}$. An *injectivity predicate* on $\mathcal{C}$ will mean a wide subcategory $\mathcal{I}$ of $\operatorname{Mono} \mathcal{C}$ such that if $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to Z$ are two morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ satisfying $gf \in \mathcal{I}\left(X,Z\right)$, then $f \in \mathcal{I}\left(X,Y\right)$. For example:

- The subcategory $\operatorname{Mono} \mathcal{C}$ is an injectivity predicate on $\mathcal{C}$.
- If $\mathcal{C}$ is a concrete category, and if $\mathcal{I}$ is the wide subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ whose morphisms are the morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$ which are injective as maps, then $\mathcal{I}$ is an injectivity predicate on $\mathcal{C}$.

Now, let $\mathcal{I}$ be an injectivity predicate on a category $\mathcal{C}$.

**(a)** Is there a category $\mathcal{D}$ such that $\mathcal{C}$ is a wide subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$ and such that the morphisms of $\mathcal{I}$ are precisely the morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$ that are monomorphisms in $\mathcal{D}$ ?

**(b)** Is there a category $\mathcal{D}$ such that $\mathcal{C}$ is a wide subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$ and such that the morphisms of $\mathcal{I}$ are precisely the monomorphisms of $\mathcal{D}$ ? (This is stronger than **(a)**, and I don't have much of a reason to hope it is true.)

**(c)** What if we drop the "wide" in **(a)**; i.e., we allow adding new objects to force morphisms not in $\mathcal{I}$ to be non-monomorphisms?

Comment: (a) What about pullbacks? Monomorphisms are stable under them.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I fear I don't have much experience with pullbacks in general concrete categories. Would you expect that injective morphisms are stable under them as well?

Comment: What I want to say is that probably not every injectivity predicate comes from monomorphisms, because monomorphisms satisfy extra conditions, for example stability under pullback.

Comment: There's a strange disconnect between the motivation and the question: from the motivation, I would have assumed that $\mathsf{Ring} \to \mathsf{Ab}$ was meant to be an example of your $\mathcal C \to \mathcal D$. But $\mathsf{Ring} \to \mathsf{Ab}$, while faithful, is not the inclusion of a subcategory -- it is not injective on objects or even "essentially" injective on objects. In any event, the answer to (a) and (b) is _no_ if $\mathcal I$ contains any morphisms which are not monic in $\mathcal C$: since faithful functors relfect monics, they will be non-monic in $\mathcal D$ as well.

Comment: @tcamps: Thanks! I've fixed the question to get rid of this counterexample (I should have thought of it while writing the question...), and got rid of the weak-ish motivation (I feel it could motivate a smarter question, but I am not sure I have the time to fine-tune it).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I am not sure of this all. What if pullbacks in $\mathcal{D}$ don't exist? What if they are not in $\mathcal{C}$, or not pullbacks in $\mathcal{C}$ ? (I admit I know very little about pullbacks.)

Comment: @darij: I am confused about the precise phrasing of the question. I would have expected it to be what I said: "what are necessary and sufficient conditions for a class of monomorphisms in $C$ to be the class of monomorphisms that remain monomorphisms after applying a faithful functor $F : C \to D$?" I don't see the point of requiring that $F$ is wide.

Comment: Indeed, I don't see the point of requiring that $F$ is a subcategory inclusion at all. What is an example of the situation you have in mind, @darij?

Comment: @tcamps: well, if you don't require that $F$ is at least faithful then it need not reflect monomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. So there is really a family of questions that it makes sense to ask: We can assume $\mathcal{I}$ to be full, wide, just a subcategory, or even just a category with a functor to $\mathcal{C}$; we can require $\mathcal{C}$ as a subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$ to be full, wide, just a subcategory, or even just a category with a functor to $\mathcal{D}$. I fear I don't have the intuitive grasp of category theory to tell which of these $4 \times 4$ versions (times $2$ for **(a)** and **(b)**, although **(b)** probably won't always make sense) is the right one. Suggestions?

Comment: Borrowing and modifying terminology from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicatively_closed_set), we might also say that an injectivity predicate is a wide subcategory of $\mathrm{Mono}\,\mathbf{C}$ that is "right-saturated." Or maybe "mono-saturated" would be a better term.